# Office365 api issue with timezone

Tags: php, calendar, timezone, office365

We create calendar events with php sdk (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)

```
…..
                'start' => [
                    'dateTime' =>'2019-04-02T12:30:00+01:00',
                    'timeZone' => 'Europe/London'
                ],
                'end' => [
                    'dateTime' => '2019-04-02T13:30:00+01:00',
                    'timeZone' => 'Europe/London'
                ],
….
```

But when we open appointment in desktop time zone always show UTC. Why ? and how to fix it ?

[Outlook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bo3O.png)

Comment: These type of time format called iso time format, You can convert it to the local timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to send these values *without* the time zone offset.  In other words, the dateTime should look like: `'2019-04-02T12:30:00'`

Also, while the documentation states that both IANA and Windows time zones are supported, [at least one other person has reported it not working with IANA zones](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4242).  If this is indeed the case, then the equivalent Windows time zone ID would be `'GMT Standard Time'`.  Hopefully it does support either, but you could try.